# fromConstrB or something other useful

Tags: haskell

I have:

```
class C a where
  anyC :: a 
data D = D String|AnyD deriving (Eq, Show, Data)
instance C D where
  anyC = AnyD
```

and I want to write function `:: C a => a` which will create `D someString`. I'll call `anyC` and get `a` which is `AnyD`. And next step is to create `D someString` from `AnyD`. In most modern languages it's easy. For Haskell I found [this tutorial](http://chrisdone.com/posts/data-typeable#fnref1) and see there `fromConstrB`. So, goal seems doable, but.. I hit problem that article looks wrong: I can't construct anything in the way of Chris because constructor argument must be algebraic type and code like `fromConstr (toConstr (1 :: Int))` returns error `Exception: Data.Data.constrIndex is not supported for Prelude.Int, as it is not an algebraic data type.`. And the same is for `String`, so I can't pass my `someString` to my constructor! How to workaround it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A definition having type

```
foo :: C a => a
```

is promising to deliver a value of *any* type `a`, as long as it is inside class `C`. The *user* of `foo` gets to choose `a`, `foo` itself can't pick a specific type.

With your setting, the only possible (non-error) definition is

```
foo = anyC
```

If you want to return `D "hello"`, then this is of type `D`. You can use that type if you want:

```
bar :: D
bar = D "hello"
```

Also note that, if you want, you can change your instance as well:

```
instance C D where
  anyC = D "hello"
```

---

Regarding

> In most modern languages it's easy.

This is actually not the case. In Java, for instance, a vague equivalent could be

```java
// the typeclass, roughly
interface C<A> {
   A anyC();
}

class D implements C<D> { ... }

<A extends C<A>> A foo() {
   return new D(...);
}
```

Java won't accept that, either. Other issues aside, `foo()` is promising to return any `A` chosen by the caller, it can't choose to return a `D`.

Haskell type variables very roughly correspond to Java's generic type parameters. You might be instead thinking about subtyping, which exists in Java and other OOP languages, but is not used by Haskell.

---

If you want a `fromConstrB` example, you can try this one:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable, ScopedTypeVariables, TypeOperators, GADTs #-}

module FromConstr where

import Data.Data

data D = D String | AnyD deriving (Show, Data)

foo :: D
foo = fromConstrB field ctor
   where
   ctor :: Constr
   ctor = toConstr (D "aaa")
   field :: forall a. Data a => a
   field = case eqT :: Maybe (a :~: String) of
      Just Refl -> "new string"
      Nothing   -> error "trying to fill a non-string field"
```

`foo` evaluates to `D "new string"`. This can be expanded so that `field` covers more types, if the constructor need more, by nesting `case eqT`s, so that we check for all needed types.

Also note that `fromConstrB` is limited since if our constructor has two fields with the same type we can't fill the fields with different values. For that, we would need to resort to the more complex `fromConstrM`, I think.

---

Here's a little convenience helper function. It takes a `Constr`, and a list of "untyped" arguments (`Dynamic` makes all the type checking at runtime), and tries to build a value applying the constructor to the given arguments.

```
applyConstr :: Data a => Constr -> [Dynamic] -> Maybe a
applyConstr ctor args = let
   nextField :: forall d. Data d => StateT [Dynamic] Maybe d
   nextField = do
      as <- get
      case as of
         [] -> lift Nothing  -- too few arguments
         (a:rest) -> do
            put rest
            case fromDynamic a of
               Nothing -> lift Nothing  -- runtime type mismatch
               Just x  -> return x
   in case runStateT (fromConstrM nextField ctor) args of
      Just (x, []) -> Just x
      _            -> Nothing  -- runtime type error or too few / too many arguments
```

For example, you can use it as follows:

```
bar :: D
bar = case applyConstr (toConstr (D "aaa")) [toDyn "hello"] of
   Just x  -> x
   Nothing -> error "runtime type mismatch"
```

If the constructor has more arguments, you only have to make the list longer, as in `[toDyn "string", toDyn (42::Int), toDyn True]`. The `toDyn` function converts typed values into "untyped" ones, so that they can be stored together in the same list, and passed to `applyConstr`. Later on `applyConstr` will test (at runtime) if this list is of the exact length, and having values of the right types.

Comment: My question is about how to call `fromConstrB` with simple (builtin) types, not about typeclasses and instances. So, in most modern languages I can: a) get all constructors b) get constructor arguments c) get types/default values for them d) even call constructor. I see example how to do it in those tutorial, but seems the tutorial lies. So, question is: how to construct value of Data-like type if I found needed constructor already? Example only illustrates the goal. Sure, it has problem: I must check that found constructor has 1 arg only and it's String

Comment: @Paul-AG See my edit on how to use `fromConstrB` and some related functions.

Comment: `nextField = StateT uncons >>= lift . fromDynamic`

Comment: hmm, seems that I was not enough attentive. Tutorial says that it's possible with `fromConstr $ toConstr s`, where `s` is some `String`, for example. @chi, thanks again!